# AFNetworking UIImageView setImageWithURLRequest returning response code 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking's UIImageView category and I am constantly getting a response code of 0 in my response code status. Any idea why this is? Here's how I am doing it:

```
[self.newsPicture_ setImageWithURLRequest:storyImageRequest 
                                         placeholderImage:nil 
                                                  success:^(NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, UIImage * image) {
                                                      if ([response statusCode] == 200){
                                                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

 });
                                                      } else {
                                                          NSLog(@"RESPONSE ERROR WITH CODE IS %d", [response statusCode]);
                                                      }
                                                  }failure:^(NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, NSError * error){
                                                      if (error){
                                                          NSLog(@"Error in requesting news story image");
                                                      }
                                                  }];
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

This is only happening when I am using the block based function call.

When I use setImageWithURL, everything works fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIImageView+AFNetworking` uses an internal cache to optimize performance in scroll views and table views. A response code of 0 means that the image came out of that internal cache without making an HTTP request. You shouldn't need to check the status code being 200 in `success`, as that's already what the success/failure distinction is doing.